# C# binding datagridviewcomboboxcolumn to list display, formatting, preferred Size error

Tags: c#, list, binding, datacolumn

I have a table payments that has a null-able integer column named payMonth. I have the following class and list:

```
public class months
{
     public int payMonth { get; set; }
     public string monthName { get; set; }
}

lstMonths = new List<months> {
   ,new months() { payMonth = 1, monthName = "jan" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 2, monthName = "feb" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 3, monthName = "mar" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 4, monthName = "apr" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 5, monthName = "may" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 6, monthName = "jun" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 7, monthName = "jul" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 8, monthName = "aug" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 9, monthName = "sep" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 10, monthName = "oct" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 11, monthName = "nov" }
   ,new months() { payMonth = 12, monthName = "dec" }};

cmbMonth = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmbMonth.DataSource = lstMonths;
cmbMonth.ValueMember = "payMonth";
cmbMonth.DisplayMember = "monthName";
cmbMonth.DataPropertyName = "payMonth";
cmbMonth.Name = "cmbPayMonth";
cmbMonth.HeaderText = "Month";
cmbMonth.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
cmbMonth.Width = 80;

dgvPayments.Columns.Insert(5, cmbMonth);
```

The problem comes here. When data is displayed in the dgv, the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbMonth shows the number values (1,2,3, ...) not the month name ('Jan','Feb','Mar', ...). And when i click the dgv it display the error: formatting, display and some times formatting, preferredSize. When I remove the DataPropertyName property, this error goes but data are not displayed. Though, the payMonth values in the table are only in the list range or is null.

This is payments table:

[image]

[image]

Whats wrong?

Comment: I see nothing suspicious in your code sample. Do you have any formatting eventhandlers for `DataGridVIew`?

Comment: No handler, but default cell style

Comment: What is type of `payMonth` column in payment table? Is it `Int32` as in months list?

Comment: Can you show full exception message and possible stack trace?

Comment: In ms access it is of type integer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143554/discussion-between-hilal-al-rajhi-and-fabio).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your update

> Database type of payMonth column is Number: integer

MS Access type `Number: integer` represent 16-bit integer - `Int16` type in .Net.
So, you should change `payMonth` property to be `short`(Int16)

```
public class months
{
    public short payMonth { get; set; }
    public string monthName { get; set; }
}
```

[List of the Most Common Data Type Mappings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320435/info-oledbtype-enumeration-vs.-microsoft-access-data-types)

Comment: I am sure that the column name in the database table is the same as DataPropertyName value. It is payMonth.